# XMPPStream Connect seems to work, but delegate method xmppStreamDidConnect not being called, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, xmpp, xmppframework

so I have a class with the following interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMPPStream.h"

@interface SignInViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PassWordTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) XMPPStream *myStream;
- (IBAction)SignInButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

Then, if the `SignInButtonPress` Method is evaluated, I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)SignInButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.myStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
    [self.myStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSString *jid = self.UserNameTextField.text;
    jid = [jid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"(at)"];

    self.myStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:self.UserNameTextField.text];
    //stream.jid = self.UserNameTextField.text;


    self.myStream.hostName = @"myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com";
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init];
    if ([self.myStream connectWithTimeout:0 error:&error] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"DId Connect!");
        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Move" sender:sender];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ou");
    }


}
```

`self.myStream connectWithTimeout` seems to run fine, error is `nil` after the call, and I get "Did Connect" in the log.

However, even though I added self as a delegate of the `xmppStream` (see beginning of method), the delegate method

```
 -(void) xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
```

does not get called, even though I have it implemented in the same class as:

```
-(void) xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    if ([sender authenticateWithPassword:self.PassWordTextField.text error:NULL] ==YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"authed!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"move" sender:sender];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Why is the method not being called, and how can I troubleshoot and/or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As I use the XMPP Framework with Swift, I am not sure whether this helps you. In order to get it running in my app, I had to make sure to implement the *XMPPStreamDelegate* Protocol as well as to inherit from *NSObject* (which is given as you are inheriting from UIViewController) like so:

**Swift:**

```
class SignInViewController: UIViewController, XMPPStreamDelegate
```

**Objective-C**

```
@interface SignInViewController : UIViewController <XMPPStreamDelegate>
```